# Lock the user account after failed login attempts with Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0

We have a Rails application that uses Auth0 for authentication.

We need to implement a behavior where the user should be locked out of the application after 10 failed login attempts.  From the current Auth0 documentation, there's nothing that suggests that Auth0 captures failed login attempts and locks the user out.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer after some research. There is an anomaly detection feature available. [Check this link for more](https://github.com/auth0/docs/blob/master/articles/anomaly-detection/index.md#customize-the-blocked-account-email).

Furthermore, the Anomaly detection feature is an add-on and requires additional subscription to be purchased from Auth0 to activate it.  We cannot configure the number of failed login attempts, it defaults to 10 from a single IP address. So it's about doling out more cash. Here's the snapshot from Auth0.

[image: Screenshot of Anomaly Detection with a banner stating that use of the tool requires an additional purchase.]